# Geany Symbol list for golang

Tags: go, configuration, ide, geany

How can I configure Geany to display structs and functions in the sidebar's  Symbols list?

Currently it says "No tags found".

Comment: What version of Geany are you running? The updated symbol parser for Go was added in 1.25.

Comment: Thank you Tim. I was using 1.23. I installed 1.25 from the source and now it works

Answer (score 0):

The parser has been added with [release 1.25](https://github.com/geany/geany/blob/1.25.0/NEWS#L78) and will be enabled, once Geany is detecting you are editing a Go file. In default this is done e.g. by loading a *.go file or by manual setting via document menu.